# Tensorflow feature columns in Dataset map Table already initialized issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I've run into an issue trying to use Tensorflow's feature_column mappings inside of a function passed in to the Dataset map method.  This happens when trying to one hot encode categorical string features of a Dataset as part of the input pipeline using Dataset.map.  The error message I'm getting is that:
    tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Table already initialized.

The following code is a basic example that recreates the problem:

```
import numpy as np    
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.lookup import index_table_from_tensor

# generate tfrecords with two string categorical features and write to file
vlists = dict(season=['Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter'],
              day=['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'])

writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter('test.tfr')
for s,d in zip(np.random.choice(vlists['season'],50), 
               np.random.choice(vlists['day'],50)):
    example = tf.train.Example(
        features = tf.train.Features(
            feature={
                'season':tf.train.Feature(
                    bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[s.encode()])),
                'day':tf.train.Feature(
                    bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[d.encode()]))
            }
        )
    )
serialized = example.SerializeToString()
writer.write(serialized)
writer.close()
```

Now there's a tfrecord file in the cwd called test.tfr with 50 records, and each record consists of two string features, 'season' and 'day',
The following will then create a Dataset that will parse the tfrecords and create batches of size 4

```
def parse_record(element):
    feats = {
        'season': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string),
        'day': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string)
    }
    return tf.parse_example(element, feats)

fname = tf.placeholder(tf.string, [])
ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(fname)
ds = ds.batch(4).map(parse_record)
```

At this point if you create an iterator and call get_next on it several times, it works as expected and you would see output like this each run:

```
iterator = ds.make_initializable_iterator()
nxt = iterator.get_next()
sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict={fname:'test.tfr'})
sess.run(nxt)
# output of run(nxt) would look like
# {'day': array([b'Sat', b'Thu', b'Fri', b'Thu'], dtype=object), 'season': array([b'Winter', b'Winter', b'Fall', b'Summer'], dtype=object)}
```

However, if I wanted to use feature_columns to one hot encode those categoricals as a Dataset transformation using map, then it runs once producing correct output, but on every subsequent call to run(nxt) it gives the Tables already initialized error, eg:

```
# using the same Dataset ds from above
season_enc = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
    key='season', vocabulary_list=vlists['season'])
season_col = tf.feature_column.indicator_column(season_enc)
day_enc = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
    key='day', vocabulary_list=vlists['day'])
day_col = tf.feature_column.indicator_column(day_enc)
cols = [season_col, day_col]

def _encode(element, feat_cols=cols):
    return tf.feature_column.input_layer(element, feat_cols)

ds1 = ds.map(_encode)
iterator = ds1.make_initializable_iterator()
nxt = iterator.get_next()
sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict={fname:'test.tfr'})
sess.run(nxt)
# first run will produce correct one hot encoded output
sess.run(nxt)
# second run will generate

W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Failed precondition: Table 
already initialized.
2018-01-25 19:29:55.802358: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] 
Failed precondition: Table already initialized.
2018-01-25 19:29:55.802612: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] 
Failed precondition: Table already initialized.
```

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Table 
   already initialized.

However, if I try to do the one hot encoding manually without feature_columns as below, then it only works if tables are created before the map function, otherwise it gives the same error above

```
# using same original Dataset ds
tables = dict(season=index_table_from_tensor(vlists['season']),
              day=index_table_from_tensor(vlists['day']))
def to_dummy(element):
    s = tables['season'].lookup(element['season'])
    d = tables['day'].lookup(element['day'])
    return (tf.one_hot(s, depth=len(vlists['season']), axis=-1),
            tf.one_hot(d, depth=len(vlists['day']), axis=-1))

ds2 = ds.map(to_dummy)
iterator = ds2.make_initializable_iterator()
nxt = iterator.get_next()
sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict={fname:'test.tfr'})
sess.run(nxt)
```

It seems as if it has something to do with the scope or namespace of the index lookup tables created by feature_columns, but I'm not sure how to figure out what's happening here, I've tried changing where and when the feature_column objects are defined, but it hasn't made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I just came here through [another recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50412495/failedpreconditionerror-table-already-initialized) and would like to propose a potential solution. Since it's pretty late for this question, I'm not sure if the problem here has been solved or not. Please correct me if there's already a good solution.

I really don't know exactly how this error happens. But learning from [canned estimator](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/dnn.py), I realize there might be an alternative way to do the job which is iterating the dataset before parsing example. One good thing for this method is to separate feature column mapping from mapping function to dataset. This may be related to the unknown cause of error here since [it is known that](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19020):

> when using hash_table in "tensorflow.python.ops.gen_lookup_ops" in tf.data.Dataset.map function
>   because tf.data.Dataset.map do not use the default graph, the hash_table can not be initialized.

I'm not sure if this will fit what you really want, but a potential example using the "test.tfr" generate in your code could be:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# using the same Dataset ds from above
vlists = dict(season=['Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter'],
              day=['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'])
season_enc = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
    key='season', vocabulary_list=vlists['season'])
season_col = tf.feature_column.indicator_column(season_enc)
day_enc = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
    key='day', vocabulary_list=vlists['day'])
day_col = tf.feature_column.indicator_column(day_enc)
cols = [season_col, day_col]

def _encode(element, feat_cols=cols):
    element = tf.parse_example(element, features=tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feat_cols))
    return tf.feature_column.input_layer(element, feat_cols)

fname = tf.placeholder(tf.string, [])
ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(fname)
ds = ds.batch(4)
ds1 = ds#.map(_encode)
iterator = ds1.make_initializable_iterator()
nxt = iterator.get_next()
nxt = _encode(nxt)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
    sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict={fname:'test.tfr'})
    print(sess.run(nxt))
    # first run will produce correct one hot encoded output
    print(sess.run(nxt))
```