# FailedPreconditionError: Table already initialized

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am reading data from tfrecords with dataset api. I am converting string data to dummy data with following code.

```
SFR1 = tf.feature_column.indicator_column(
    tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list("SFR1 ",
                                                             vocabulary_list=("1", "2")))
```

But when i run my code, tensorflow is throwing following error.

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Table
>   already initialized.   [[Node:
>   Generator/input_layer/SFR1 _indicator/SFR1 _lookup/hash_table/table_init
>   = InitializeTableV2[Tkey=DT_STRING, Tval=DT_INT64](Generator/input_layer/SFR1 _indicator/SFR1 _lookup/hash_table,
>   Generator/input_layer/SFR1 _indicator/SFR1 _lookup/Const,
>   Generator/input_layer/SFR1 _indicator/SFR1 _lookup/ToInt64)]]
>      [[Node: Generator2/IteratorGetNext =
>   IteratorGetNextoutput_shapes=[[?,10000,160]],
>   output_types=[DT_FLOAT],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

I have tried many combinations to determine the source of problem. I understood that this problem occurs when model includes both `tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list` and `dataset` api. If i choose `TFRecordReader` instead of `dataset`, code is running.

When i search stackoverflow, I noticed that there is a similar issue. I am adding issue link below. As both problem are same, I didn't copy all my code. Below link includes enough data to explain my problem

[Tensorflow feature columns in Dataset map Table already initialized issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48450785/tensorflow-feature-columns-in-dataset-map-table-already-initialized-issue)

Thanks.

Comment: I just gave [a potential answer to that similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48450785/tensorflow-feature-columns-in-dataset-map-table-already-initialized-issue/50432666#50432666). If you are OK with parsing examples in TFRecord after iterating the dataset, please go check it out.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I checked your solution in my example. it is working but how can i run parallel? parallellization parameter is in map function. I have one more question. read_up_to is fast way to read tfrecords. Is there any solution like "read_up_to" in dataset?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really know how to use `tf.feature_column` in map. I don't think it will be straight forward since map has its own graph independent from the "main" graph. I think one thought here is that you are parsing and transforming/pre-processing data batch by batch. So you might be able to use some parallelism in a way similar to how you would do distributed training. I do realize this might not satisfy what you need though.

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same issue. Then modified my code following the warning from Tensorflow and it works:

**Creating lookup tables inside a function passed to Dataset.map() is not supported.** Create each table outside the function, and capture it inside the function to use it.

Hope it would help.

Comment: Thank you! By capturing you meant passing the table object into the map function as an argument, just to clarify for others.

Answer (score 0):

This is issue with earlier version of TensorFlow, updating to TF2.0 should resolve this.

**pip install --upgrade tensorflow**